# A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process, on Azure Application Logs

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, 32bit-64bit, kudu

We're running an ASP.NET 4.7.2 site on a 32bit Azure App Service. The site is deployed using Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.9), using the 'Any CPU' profile.

When using the Application Logs Stream, through the Azure interface, we're seeing lots of errors that imply that 64bit modules are present, but that can't be accessed.

Here is an example of the errors:

```
2019-03-14T21:04:19      Error occurred, type: error, text: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process., stackTrace:    at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_Modules()
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.ProcessController.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<GetProcessInfo>b__2() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\ProcessController.cs:line 446
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.ProcessController.SafeGetValue[T](Func`1 func, T defaultValue) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\ProcessController.cs:line 531
2019-03-14T21:04:19      Error occurred, type: error, text: A 32 bit processes cannot access modules of a 64 bit process., stackTrace:    at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetModuleInfos(Int32 processId, Boolean firstModuleOnly)
   at System.Diagnostics.NtProcessManager.GetFirstModuleInfo(Int32 processId)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.get_MainModule()
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.ProcessController.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<GetProcessInfo>b__3() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\ProcessController.cs:line 447
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.ProcessController.SafeGetValue[T](Func`1 func, T defaultValue) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\ProcessController.cs:line 531
2019-03-14T21:04:19      Error occurred, type: error, text: D:\local\LocalAppData\SnapshotUploader\SnapshotUploader.exe, stackTrace:    at System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(String fileName)
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule.get_FileVersionInfo()
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.ProcessController.GetProcessModuleInfo(ProcessModule module, String href, Boolean details) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\ProcessController.cs:line 401
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.ProcessController.GetModules(Process process, String href) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\ProcessController.cs:line 345
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.ProcessController.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<GetProcessInfo>b__22() in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\ProcessController.cs:line 472
   at Kudu.Services.Performance.ProcessController.SafeGetValue[T](Func`1 func, T defaultValue) in C:\Kudu Files\Private\src\master\Kudu.Services\Diagnostics\ProcessController.cs:line 531
```

We're not encountering any issues locally, but seeing wildly high CPU usage on Azure (which may or may not be related).

Building/running locally does not report anything relating to 64bit processes.

Is this a problem with our site, or with the platform? If it's a problem with us, how do we weed out rogue 64bit code? Or, do we just switch to a 64bit process and be done with it?

Our preference would be to continue in a 32bit setup. I realise this error has come up on SO before, but always (as far as I can see) in relation to Windows dev. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before checking the Application Log stream in Azure Portal, can you please check the below to make sure Visual Studio and App Service properties are set accordingly.

1. Have you looked at project properties in Visual Studio and checked the option to use 'Prefer 32Bit'
2. Have you updated to use your app platform in Azure portal to use 32 Bit ? This will be under Application Settings in your App Service.
3. Are you combining more than one project. It looks like the 32 bit project is trying to execute code that was compiled in 64 bit mode

Comment: Thanks for the response @MonikaReddy-MSFT. As far as I'm aware 'Prefer 32bit' isn't applicable to ASP.NET projects. Could you confirm? I stated in the question that the Azure service is running as 32bit. Also stated in the question, we're not building anything specifically in 64bit, as we're using 'Any CPU'. A don't know how this impacts Nuget packages though.